# I need to discover onvif camera in python using Ws-Discovery, but script can't find it , camera IP APTI-303pv2-28WP

Tags: python, web-services, camera, onvif

I have KAMERA IP APTI-303PV2-28WP, and i am using python + onvif library. To discover i am using ws-discovery , and scrip can't find my camera. I used they app BitVision , this android app found it. My question is: Can i discover this camera, or this camera i undiscoverable from manufacture? In option camera discovery mode is " discoverable" , so my opinion is i can but i dont know how.
My code is from github

```
def display(any_list):
for item in any_list:
    print(item)

def fetch_devices():
wsd = WSDiscovery()
scope1 = Scope('onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile/T')
wsd.start()
services = wsd.searchServices(scopes=[scope1])
ipaddresses = []
for service in services:
#filter those devices that dont have ONVIF service
    ipaddress = re.search('(\d+|\.)+', str(service.getXAddrs()[0])).group(0)
    ipaddresses.append(ipaddress)
    print(display(service.getScopes()))
    print('----------END')

print(f'\nnumber of devices detected: {len(services)}')
wsd.stop()

return ipaddresses


if __name__ == "__main__":
onvif_devices_IPs = fetch_devices()
display(onvif_devices_IPs)
```

I could not find any usefull help, all i found doesn't help my problem, so i have a conclusion that my camera can't be discovered from producer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you device supports the profile T?

You can try:

```
scope1 = Scope('onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am not working on this project anymore, but that was a problem, that camera was not accessable. Scopes doesn't change anything, doesn't matter what property added.